# Is AnySearch browser extension from Apple's Extension Gallery malware?

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extensions

I installed the [AnySearch](https://safari-extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.matt-swain.anysearch-6M853ET88Q) extension from Apple's Safari Browser extension Gallery and found it handy.  Then [Malwarebytes](https://malwarebytes.com/) performed a scan and it auto-deleted the extension listing it as a "threat". That's strange as this is an old extension, is installed directly from Apple's site, and I find it quite helpful.

The only reference to similar-named malware I found is [Anysearch virus](https://www.2-spyware.com/remove-search-anysearch-net-virus.html).

So I wonder: Is the extension from the extension gallery malware or is Malwarebytes marking it wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily download the extension from the gallery directly and extract it.

```
$ curl -sO https://safari-extensions.apple.com/extensions/com.matt-swain.anysearch-6M853ET88Q/anysearch.safariextz
$ xar -x -f anysearch.safariextz
$ ls -l AnySearch.safariextension/
total 88
-rw-r--r--  1 pse  staff  2182 Feb 28 15:23 Info.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 pse  staff  1988 Feb 28 15:23 Settings.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 pse  staff   190 Feb 28 15:23 global.html
-rw-r--r--  1 pse  staff  2651 Feb 28 15:23 global.js
-rw-r--r--  1 pse  staff  9707 Feb 28 15:23 icon-128.png
-rw-r--r--  1 pse  staff  4424 Feb 28 15:23 icon-64.png
-rw-r--r--  1 pse  staff   387 Feb 28 15:23 toolbar.png
-rw-r--r--  1 pse  staff   708 Feb 28 15:23 toolbar@2x.png
```

From looking at `global.html` and `global.js` there doesn't seem to be anything fishy going on.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's a malware.

it will hijack chrome or firefox search engine, also when install browser plugin in , it will generates a application named SearchFunction which has root right, could delete file / open firewall / call itself by taskgated. Simply to say it has hook  preventing user deleting itself.

```
    0    125 taskgated        3 /Users/yourname/Library/Application Support/com.SearchFunction
    0    125 taskgated        3 /Users/yourname/Library/Application Support/com.SearchFunction
    0    125 taskgated        3 /Users/yourname/Library/Application Support/com.SearchFunction/SearchFunction
```

Comment: As we seem to have proven in this thread, there are two different programs under that name. Did you get yours from the official extension gallery?

Comment: Searchfunction maybe bind with host program, when install host program will also install searchfunction automatically.

`com.SearchFunction` is a folder
`SearchFunction` the main program of this malware.